# Graphics not centering properly

Tags: graphics, miktex

I am inserting an image into my document using

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth,natwidth=338,natheight=176]{images/cloud_stack.png}
\caption{Service model stack}
\label{fig:cloud_stack}
\end{figure}
```

The image ends up being slightly off-center to the left (the caption is centered correctly). 
[image: Caption is centered, image not]

This is happening for all of the images in the document. Tables are centered correctly. I'm using TeXstudio's DVI->PDF chain with MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows.

**Edit:**
Using `\fbox{\includegraphics{..}}` shows extra whitespace inside the box:
[image: Extra whitespace inside the box]

Comment: for testing use `\fbox{\includegraphics{..}}` if the white space is _inside_ the box, then the white space is part of the image (or tex thinks it is)

Comment: why are you specifying `natwidth=338,natheight=176` if you don't do that pdflatex will use the exact image measurement, if you override that you need to make sure you are exactly correct oh I see you are using dvi OK but make sure the dimension is correct:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not adding it makes the compiler fail with the error 'Cannot determine size of graphics (no BoundingBox)'. The sizes are correct

Comment: yes I saw you are using dvi output so you do need to tell it the size, are you sure the size is correct (in `bp` units) not being correct would explain the output you get:-)

Comment: as I suspected Tex is centering something based on the size you said the image is, but it's much smaller

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I specified the natwidth and natheight in `px`. I'll convert them and try gain. If you want to add that as an answer I'll be happy to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default units for `natheight` and `natwidth` keys are `bp` (so that it matches the units of an EPS BoundingBox comment). Using `\fbox` you can see the actual size of the image is much smaller but classic TeX can not see that and uses whatever size you give.

If instead you used pdflatex then you could omit the `natheight` and `natwidth` keys and let the system measure the image exactly as it includes it.